# how to give reference for static inner class while creating object?

Tags: java

I have classes below, I will create object for inner class however I have doubt on creating object for inner class.

```
class parent{

    String name;

    public static class inner {
        String name;
    }
}

class Main {
    parent p = new parent();
    parent.inner in = new inner() //when do i have to create like this?
    parent.inner in = new Parent.inner()  //when do i have to create like this?

}
```

I have created two ways to create object for inner class but what is the different between those? which one is correct?

if both are correct then which scenario i have to create like above?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: You only need the second way if there's a naming conflict or if you only want to import the outer class.

Comment: Java is a case-sensitive language.  By convention, classes should begin with an upper-case letter (`Parent`, `Inner`).  But in any case, the letter case has to match, so you can't mix `Parent` and `parent` and expect them to mean the same thing.

Comment: Btw, `inner` is not actually an inner class, just a static nested class.

Comment: The question is about visibility.  `Parent.Inner` always works.  `Inner` by itself only works from code inside `Parent`, unless you import `Parent.Inner`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you can't access `parent.inner in = new inner()` in you `Main class`
Because you can't directly access this class member without class name or Object

go through this link [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject = new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();  //static classes
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass(); // non-static classes
```

Comment: if i import Parent.Inner and if i create object like Parent.inner in = new inner(), will this work?

Comment: @adithyan.p (1) Nothing will work unless you write it `Inner` instead of `inner`.  (2) _Each identifier_ is interpreted according to the visibility rules, independent of the rest of the statement.  So if you have to say `Parent.Inner` at the beginning of the declaration, then you also have to say `new Parent.Inner`.  Using `Parent.Inner` at the beginning doesn't make `Inner` visible anywhere else.  (You could have another class named `Inner` that extends `Parent.Inner`... it's not uncommon for classes in different packages to share names like this.)